# После обновлений mysql не стартует

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, mysql

Перестал стартовать mysql, вообще не работает. Вот что откапал.

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Вт 2016-07-12 20:45:27 MSK; 11s ago
  Process: 11828 ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post (code=killed, signal=TERM)
  Process: 11827 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 11823 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 11827 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

июл 12 20:45:20 denis-desktop systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
июл 12 20:45:20 denis-desktop systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
июл 12 20:45:22 denis-desktop systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
июл 12 20:45:27 denis-desktop systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
июл 12 20:45:27 denis-desktop systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
июл 12 20:45:27 denis-desktop systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
июл 12 20:45:29 denis-desktop systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
июл 12 20:45:30 denis-desktop systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
```

Переустановки или установки mysql-server не дают положительного результата

```
Распаковывается mysql-server (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1) …
Обрабатываются триггеры для man-db (2.7.5-1) …
Обрабатываются триггеры для systemd (229-4ubuntu6) …
Обрабатываются триггеры для ureadahead (0.100.0-19) …
Настраивается пакет mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1) …
Настраивается пакет mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1) …
Устанавливается новая версия файла настройки /etc/init.d/mysql …
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет mysql-server:
 mysql-server зависит от mysql-server-5.7, однако:
  Пакет mysql-server-5.7 пока не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета mysql-server (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
Обрабатываются триггеры для systemd (229-4ubuntu6) …
Обрабатываются триггеры для ureadahead (0.100.0-19) …
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Снес mysql-(server, client) поставил mariadb-(все что и тама и более) пару трюков

1.Установка пароля https://codeby.net/programmy-dlja-servera/kak-sbrosit-parol-root-mariadb/
2.Иза чего-то подключатся не хотел(из рута только подключался) решилось этим https://superuser.com/questions/957708/mysql-mariadb-error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost (способ 1)

Все работает!! И ставится все ок.